# Android Studio: Preview of the phone, only screen is showing, not the surroundings of the screen

Tags: java, android, xml, preview

My preview of the phone on Android Studio is broken. It only shows the screen and it has this weird white bar under the actual parent view. Can somebody tell me what's causing it? Here's an image:

[image]

Comment: is the behavior in the `Design` mode the same?

Answer (score 2):

In the newer versions of Android studio, you can show device frame just by pressing "F" from your keyboard.

That's all!

Answer (score 1):

Go to setting icon (first from right with options ) => Select "Include device frame if available"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That happens when your root `ViewGroup` is `ScrollView`. This is probably so that we can see the entirely of the layout while designing. To toggle it, simply click on your root `ScrollView` and click on the left-most button in the options that appear below the phone selection dropdown in layout-editor. I've added the image for reference:

[image]